# What is a service in APM?

Tags: apm

from the docs of APM: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/get-started/7.12/transactions.html

> Transactions are a special kind of span that have additional
> attributes associated with them. They describe an event captured by an
> Elastic APM agent instrumenting a service. You can think of
> transactions as the highest level of work you’re measuring within a
> service. As an example, a transaction might be a: ...

How is a "service" defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Service is an application that is connected to the APM server via a connection and sends all of the metrics to the server.
Almost all of the backend languages connects to the APM using a client library.
I use it in Golang, the library has an agent that wraps the router and captures all metrics. In both of HTTP and GRPC.